# Is there a way to encrypt the configuration file of a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, configuration-files

Is there a way to encrypt the configuration file of a Windows forms application?

All I can find on google is stuff that is dependant on "aspnet_regiis.exe" but I want to do this for a desktop application?

e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx

Comment: You wish to protect the contents of your car. You lock the keys inside a strong box, and hide the box and its key under the car. Good idea?

Your problem is not a problem that can be solved by encryption, so don't try. *If you don't trust the user then you need to harden the server*. Attackers are not going to mess around with your client application; they're going to write their own clients.

Comment: @Eric: Very well said.  However, he's asking to make it impossible for attackers to write their own clients by encrypting the key.  As I said in my second answer, it can be made difficult, but not impossible.  As you pointed out, once they have the connection string, there's nothing more that he can do.

Comment: That said, it is a good idea to encrypt passwords in a config file *to protect the user's password from an attacker mounting attacks against that user*. The vulnerability that encryption mitigates is *not* "hostile user attacks my database", it's "hostile third party obtains unauthorized access to my user's config file containing their password".

Comment: @Eric#2: That's also very true; that's what I addressed in the second half of my first answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?

Remember that the program itself needs to decrypt the file, and, in your case, the EXE file will be on the end-users machines.
Therefore, anyone who has access to the config file will almost definitely have the EXE as well, and there is no way to prevent them from reading it.

If you're storing the end-user's password and want to prevent other people from reading it, you could call [`File.Encrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt.aspx) on the path to the file.  Note that this won't work in XP Home.

You can also use the [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class in System.Security.dll to encrypt a byte array such that only the logged on user can decrypt it, then store that byte array in the config file.  (This will work in XP home, AFAIK)

Comment: I am trying to produce an application which will need to have access to a database to pull information from which I don't want the application user to have access to and I don't want them to see the connection string to the database. Which is also why I can't use integrated security...

Comment: You're out of luck; that's not possible. Remember that the user can do anything that the application can do using Reflector and a debugger.

Comment: Or, another way of putting that is that an application can do only those things that the user can do; *an application acts on behalf of the user*. If the application can do X, then clearly the user must have been able to do X, since the application can only do what the user already can do.  If the application can decrypt the config file and connect to the database, then the user can too.

Comment: @Eric: That line is usually used in reverse, when people want Windows to only allow something to be done by the user, not any application.

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

It is not possible to stop a determined user.  If the user tries hard enough, there is *nothing* you can do to prevent him from doing what an application on his machine is able to do.  You can make it exceedingly difficult, but not impossible.

What exactly are you afraid that the user will do?

If you only want him to be able to see some of the data, you can use database permissions or stored procedures, or replace the database with a web service.
If you don't want him to be able to copy the data, there's no 100% solution.

You can obfuscate the assembly, but no obfuscator is completely perfect.
You can add lines like `if (Debugger.IsAttached) Environment.FailFast()`, but the user can remove them with [Reflexil](http://code.google.com/p/reflexil/).
You can use a hash of the assembly file as (part of) the encryption key, but the user can replace it with a hard-coded byte array using Reflexil.
If you replace the database with a web service, you could modify the web service to detect suspicious requests, but the user could wait between requests and/or use different machines.
You could return images instead of data, but the user can use OCR.

In short, you can make it very difficult and time-consuming, but you can't make it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I applied a working solution to your need. Here is the link to it.

http://www.ardabasoglu.com/1/post/2010/12/encrypting-the-windows-forms-application-settings.html